# Verilog code I2C to vhdl

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I need to write some code from verilog to vhdl. The code i need to rewrite is for a camera on a de2-115 fpga. What did i wrong?

This is the verilog code from Altera. I editted it a little bit to test some things. But it still works. I don't understand why this code does have two if statements with the same condition. I have tried it with one if and then it doesn't work. In the VHDL code i've tried also one and two if statement with the reset = '0' condition, but it still not works.

```
    module I2C_Controller (
        CLOCK,
        I2C_SCLK,//I2C CLOCK
        I2C_SDAT,//I2C DATA
        I2C_DATA,//DATA:[SLAVE_ADDR,SUB_ADDR,DATA]
        GO,      //GO transfor
        EEND,     //END transfor 
        W_R,     //W_R
        ACK,      //ACK
        RESET

    );
        input  CLOCK;
        input  [31:0]I2C_DATA;  
        input  GO;
        input  RESET;   
        input  W_R;
        inout  I2C_SDAT;    
        output I2C_SCLK;
        output EEND;    
        output ACK;

    reg SDO;
    reg SCLK;
    reg EEND;
    reg [31:0]SD;
    reg [6:0]SD_COUNTER;

    wire I2C_SCLK=SCLK | ( ((SD_COUNTER >= 4) & (SD_COUNTER <=39))? ~CLOCK :0 );
    wire I2C_SDAT=SDO?1'bz:0 ;

    reg ACK1;
    wire ACK=ACK1;

    //--I2C COUNTER
    always @(negedge RESET or posedge CLOCK ) begin
    if (!RESET) SD_COUNTER=6'b111111;
    else begin
    if (GO==0) 
        SD_COUNTER=0;
        else 
        if (SD_COUNTER < 41) SD_COUNTER=SD_COUNTER+1;   
    end

    if (!RESET) begin SCLK=1;SDO=1; ACK1=0; EEND=1; end
    else
    case (SD_COUNTER)
        6'd0  : begin ACK1=0 ; EEND=0; SDO=1; SCLK=1;end
        //start
        6'd1  : begin SD=I2C_DATA;SDO=0;end
        6'd2  : SCLK=0;
        //SLAVE ADDR
        6'd3  : SDO=SD[31];
        6'd4  : SDO=SD[30];
        6'd5  : SDO=SD[29];
        6'd6  : SDO=SD[28];
        6'd7  : SDO=SD[27];
        6'd8  : SDO=SD[26];
        6'd9  : SDO=SD[25];
        6'd10 : SDO=SD[24]; 
        6'd11 : SDO=1'b1;//ACK

        //SUB ADDR
        6'd12  : begin SDO=SD[23]; ACK1=I2C_SDAT; end
        6'd13  : SDO=SD[22];
        6'd14  : SDO=SD[21];
        6'd15  : SDO=SD[20];
        6'd16  : SDO=SD[19];
        6'd17  : SDO=SD[18];
        6'd18  : SDO=SD[17];
        6'd19  : SDO=SD[16];
        6'd20  : SDO=1'b1;//ACK

        //DATA
        6'd21  : begin SDO=SD[15]; ACK1=I2C_SDAT; end
        6'd22  : SDO=SD[14];
        6'd23  : SDO=SD[13];
        6'd24  : SDO=SD[12];
        6'd25  : SDO=SD[11];
        6'd26  : SDO=SD[10];
        6'd27  : SDO=SD[9];
        6'd28  : SDO=SD[8];
        6'd29  : SDO=1'b1;//ACK

        //DATA
        6'd30  : begin SDO=SD[7]; ACK1=I2C_SDAT; end
        6'd31  : SDO=SD[6];
        6'd32  : SDO=SD[5];
        6'd33  : SDO=SD[4];
        6'd34  : SDO=SD[3];
        6'd35  : SDO=SD[2];
        6'd36  : SDO=SD[1];
        6'd37  : SDO=SD[0];
        6'd38  : SDO=1'b1;//ACK


        //stop
         6'd39 : begin SDO=1'b0; SCLK=1'b0; ACK1=I2C_SDAT; end  
         6'd40 : SCLK=1'b1; 
         6'd41 : begin SDO=1'b1; EEND=1; end 

    endcase
    end

    endmodule
```

This is the VHDL code:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

entity II2C_Controller is
PORT 
(
    CLOCK   : in std_logic;
    I2C_SCLK : out std_logic;
    I2C_SDAT : inout std_logic;
    I2C_DATA : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    GO          : in std_logic;
    EEND        : out std_logic;
    W_R         : in std_logic;
    ACK         : out std_logic;
    RESET   : in std_logic
);
end entity II2C_Controller;

architecture arch_i2c of II2C_Controller is 

begin

pclk : PROCESS(CLOCK, RESET)

variable SD_COUNTER : integer;
variable SDO, ACK1, SCLK : std_logic;
variable SD : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

begin
    if (RESET = '0') then
        SD := i2c_DATA;
        SD_COUNTER := 127;  
    elsif(RISing_edge(CLOCK)) then
        if(GO = '0') then
            SD_COUNTER := 0;
        elsif(SD_COUNTER < 41) then
            SD_COUNTER := SD_COUNTER + 1;
        end if;
    end if;

    if (RESET = '0') then
        SCLK := '1';
        SDO := '1'; 
        ACK <= '0';
        EEND <= '1';
    elsif(rising_edge(CLOCK)) then

        ACK <= ACK1;

    if SDO = '1' then
        I2C_SDAT <= 'Z';
    else 
        I2C_SDAT <= '0'; --Z means pullup
    end if;

    if(SCLK = '1') then
        I2C_SCLK <= SCLK;
    elsif(SD_COUNTER >= 4 and SD_COUNTER <=39) then
        I2C_SCLK <= not clock;
    else
        I2C_SCLK <= '0';
    end if;

        case SD_COUNTER is
            when 0 =>
                ACK <= '0';
                SCLK := '1';
                SDO := '1'; 
                EEND <= '0';
            when 1 => 
                SDO := '0';
            when 2 => sclK := '0';
            when 3 => SDO := SD(31);
            when 4 => SDO := SD(30);
            when 5 => SDO := SD(29);
            when 6 => SDO := SD(28);
            when 7 => SDO := SD(27);
            when 8 => SDO := SD(26);
            when 9 => SDO := SD(25);
            when 10 => SDO := SD(24);
            when 11 => SDO := '1';

            when 12 => SDO := SD(23);
                          ACK <= I2c_SDAT;
            when 13 => SDO := SD(22);
            when 14 => SDO := SD(21);
            when 15 => SDO := SD(20);
            when 16 => SDO := SD(19);
            when 17 => SDO := SD(18);
            when 18 => SDO := SD(17);
            when 19 => SDO := SD(16);
            when 20 => SDO := '1';

            when 21 => SDO := SD(15);
                          ACK <= I2C_SDAT;
            when 22 => SDO := SD(14);
            when 23 => SDO := SD(13);
            when 24 => SDO := SD(12);
            when 25 => SDO := SD(11);
            when 26 => SDO := SD(10);
            when 27 => SDO := SD(9);
            when 28 => SDO := SD(8);
            when 29 => SDO := '1';

            when 30 => SDO := SD(7); 
                          ACK <= I2C_SDAT;
            when 31 => SDO := SD(6);
            when 32 => SDO := SD(5);
            when 33 => SDO := SD(4);
            when 34 => SDO := SD(3);
            when 35 => SDO := SD(2);
            when 36 => SDO := SD(1);
            when 37 => SDO := SD(0);
            when 38 => SDO := '1';

            when 39 => SDO := '0';
                          SCLK := '0'; 
                          ACK <= I2C_SDAT;
            when 40 => SCLK := '1';
            when 41 => SDO := '1';
                          EEND <= '1';

            when others => NULL;
        end case;
    end if;

end process;

end architecture arch_i2c;
```

Comment: "it still not works" is not a problem description. You need to explain in what way it is not working. Perhaps you have some simulation output you could add.

Comment: I've tried to make a waveform simulation, but I can't test this code with a waveform. The I2C_SDAT & I2C_SCLK do not change in the waveform.

Comment: I would suggest actually understanding the verilog implementation, reverse engineering it, and reconstructing it in VHDL. You seem to have done a direct translation with no understanding...

Comment: It's not a direct translation, there are several errors.

Comment: Your post does not appear compatible with the [original's](https://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece5760/DE2/AudioFilter_oct2009/AudioFilter_oct2009/I2C_Controller.v) license terms. An X-HDL translated version ([I2C_Controller.vhd](http://read.pudn.com/downloads97/sourcecode/embed/395088/I2C_Controller.vhd__.htm)) substituting **std_logic** for **bit** and an added context clause shows where your hand translation has gone astray. Provide an [MCVe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a specific problem.